# Javascript load error while installing Sourcetree in Windows 7

Tags: javascript, windows, installation, atlassian-sourcetree

I am getting the following error while trying to install Sourcetree in Windows 7(32-bit) Environment.

```
Atlassian

JavaScript load error
We tried to load scripts but something went wrong.

Please make sure that your network settings allow you to download scripts from the following domain:

https://common-admin-cdn.atlassian.com/atlassian-id/front-end/2.1.3
```

Version used is [SourceTree-2.3.5.0](https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/ga/SourceTreeSetup-2.3.5.0.exe?_ga=2.260741197.1953918121.1511645984-410379396.1511645984)

[[image: Error screenshot[1]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try to this solution:

- In Internet Explorer, goto Tool -> Internet Option -> Security tab.

-> select Internet icon -> Select Custom Level -> at **Active scripting** choose Enable -> OK

Now you need to retry the installing of SourceTree, it was solved.
[image]

Comment: IMPORTANT!!! you also have to Find "Access data sources across domains" and select "Enable" (make note of what the setting currently is)

Answer (score 6):

I fix this problem updating my Internet Explorer from 8 to 11.

For some reason, IE8 can't execute the javascript on Atlassian login page even when I try to enable to execute following this [steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135465/how-to-enable-javascript-in-windows).

Answer (score 3):

First uninstall current sourceTree

and install old version of Source tree

download from [here](https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.4.1.exe?_ga=2.209835605.1997806463.1512026957-798479474.1511276316)

Comment: when you update, the problem is again, install IE 11 for repair that

Answer (score 1):

same here.

JavaScript load error

We tried to load scripts but something went wrong.

Please make sure that your network settings allow you to download scripts from the following domain:

https://common-admin-cdn.atlassian.com/atlassian-id/front-end/2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Just Install the new version of IE, 11 in this moment ->[Link](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. The simplest solution is to install Interent Explorer 11 as it updates some critical required files for windows 7. Be sure to download correct IE 11 as per 32 or 64 bit

**Solution Hightlight
Install Internet Explorer 11**